# On calling destructor for an object, it is called two times?

Tags: c++, destructor

On calling desctructor explicitly, it is executed two times. What's the reason for that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int x;

        A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;  }

        ~A(){
            cout<<"A's desctructor called "<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;
    a.~A();
}
```

Output:

> A's constructor called
>   A's desctructor called
>   A's desctructor called

Comment: The first destructor is for `a` the second is for `b`.

Comment: [That's not the output I get.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdf2b2f6554a097c)

Comment: There is no reason besides the misunderstanding that any object in a scope is cleaned up by a desstructor.

Comment: I see undefined behavior above: anything is allowed to happen!

Answer (score 6):

Well, you called it for 'a', and then 'the language' called it again for 'a' when the object went out of scope. And then, of course, 'the language' called it for b. By 'the language', I mean, of course, the very basic rule that automatic-scope objects are constructed as their scope initialize, and destructed when their scope ends.

Using explicit calls to destructors is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I believe that the destructor for `b` is not called because `b` is not used and not even constructed.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't call the destructor by hand, it will get called automatically when the object goes out of scope.

The only place to manually call destructors is when you're writing your own allocator, but that is quite an advanced topic, so the rule of thumb would be to never call the destructor by hand.

Comment: That is not the only case for manually calling destructors.  `boost::variant` will do so, for example.

Comment: @Yakk which is similar to an allocator for a single object (placement new)

Answer (score 3):

[basic.life]/8:

> If a program ends the lifetime of an object of type `T` with […]
>   automatic (3.7.3) storage duration and if `T` has a non-trivial
>   destructor, **the program must ensure that an object of the original
>   type occupies that same storage location when the implicit destructor
>   call takes place;** **otherwise the behavior of the program is undefined.**

Hence we cannot explain the behavior of your program in general, but we could say "For your implementation a particular execution behaved as if the destructor was called two times."

Comment: Not quite: the explanation really is "there is undefined behavior, as there is no `A` object living in `a` anymore as it was destroyed.  Today, that undefined behavior looks like a destructor call."

Comment: @Yakk Adapted yours. How is it now?

Comment: I should never have added to a comment thread with about the standard.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable goes out of scope, its destructor is implicitly called.

If the there is no object of the appropriate type there, the behavior is undefined.  Typically the compiler generates code that would call the destructor and does so blindly, as that makes the 'defined behavior' path efficient and simple, and the 'undefined behavior' path is considered your fault.

So what you are seeing is a symptom of undefined behavior.  Your call of the destructor **does not** mean the compiler will not try to destroy the object.

In fact, if your object was slightly more complex, it could easily lead to a crash.

Don't call the destructor of an object directly unless you used placement new (a variant of `new` that constructs an object and does not allocate any memory) or the equivalent on it, and don't use placement new unless you really know what you are doing.

There is another valid use, where you destruct and reconstruct in the same place, but that is dangerous, usually a bad idea, and hard to get right.